# mapToDouble is not applicable in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, sum, java-stream

I have a list of amount that I need to compute or summarize. I converted it to double before summarizing. The problem is I get error using stream.mapToDouble. It says 'The method mapToDouble(ToDoubleFunction<? super Service.Report>) in the type Stream<Service.Report> is not applicable for the arguments (double)'.

I'm not sure why it is wrong, I thought the code was right.

```
         result.entrySet()
    .forEach(entry -> {
        
        String amthere = entry.getValue().get(5).tranamt; // list of amount
        double Amt = Double.parseDouble(amthere);           
        double sumAmtF = entry.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Amt).sum();
        
        sb.append("&lt;rf2:TotalCollection")        
        .append(" rf2:location=").append("\"").append(entry.getKey()).append("\"") 
        .append(" rf2:totalamount=").append("\"").append(sumAmt).append("\"").append("&gt;"); 
                           

    });     
    });
```

Comment: The argument of `mapToDouble` must be a `ToDoubleFunction` - something that takes a value from the stream and converts it to a `double` value. I'm not clear what you are trying to do with mapToDouble in your code.

Comment: @greg-449 It still gives me an error. You're right I wanted to get a value from the list of String. convert that value into Double then compute or summarize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `entry.getValue()` seems to be a list of `Service.Report`. You must select `tranamt` attribute and after `mapToDouble()` must parse each `tranamt` into double before summing.

```
double sumAmtF = entry.getValue()
  .stream()
  .map(report -> report.tranamt) // select tranamt attribute value
  .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble) // parse each tranamt attribute value into double
  .sum();
```